# How to add a button on the Product page / How to add size-chart in magento /

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

Website URL- niraame.com

This is our website URL. We want to add size-chart option in our cloth section.
I have little knowledge of JavaScript and HTML so i have created a button which does exactly what i wanted to do.

JavaScript and HTML code which i stored as a Static block in Magento-

```
<p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
 function popup(){
  sizeWindow = window.open("http://localhost/magento/media/wysiwyg/s.jpg", "sizeWindow", "location=no,width=520,height=520"); 
}
// ]]></script>
</p>
 <p><strong><a href="javascript:popup()">Size Chart</a></strong></p>
```

This code displays a button on the screen and after clicking it we gets the sizechart loaded on a popup window.

I am not able to figure out how to put this button on the Product page.
I tried finding an answer on the Community page.

Can anyone please tell me how to add a button on Product page.

Answer (score 1):

The template that renders the html for the product page is `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/catalog/product/view.phtml`.
Put your code in there.
But please don't use hard coded links like `http://localhost/magento/media/wysiwyg/s.jpg`.
Use

```
window.open("<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media')?>/s.jpg", "sizeWindow", "location=no,width=520,height=520");
```

Comment: Sir as per your instructions i changed the view.phtml page. But  i am getting same size chart for every product. Is there any way to different size-charts for different sections. For example for Male section we have different size chart and for female section we have different size-chart. Can you please tell me how to do that

Comment: That's a totally different issue. From what I understood you wanted a simple way to display an image in the product view page.

Comment: @ Marius Sir actually i am trying to add size chart for different product category in my website